# Custom CV in RecursiveFeatureAddition, list index out of range

Tags: cross-validation, fold

I have the following problem
'List index out of range'

Here my code:

```
rfa2_search = RecursiveFeatureAddition(mod_XG, scoring=accuracy, cv=folds, threshold=0.01)
```

folds variable is obtained through this split:

```
def walk_forward(df_train, n_fold, zip_):
    # non-overlapping walk forward
    
    total_points = df_train.shape[0] # 5000
    
    sub_val_points = int(0.5 * total_points / n_fold) # 500
    sub_train_points = int(total_points - sub_val_points * n_fold) # 2500

    arr_tra, arr_val = [], []
    step = sub_val_points # non overlapping criteria
    pos = 0
    
    for _ in range(n_fold):
        arr_tra.append(np.arange(pos, pos + sub_train_points))
        arr_val.append(np.arange(pos + sub_train_points, pos + sub_train_points + sub_val_points))
        
        pos += step
    
    if zip_:
        custom_cv = zip(list(arr_tra), list(arr_val))
    else:
        custom_cv = [list(arr_tra), list(arr_val)]
          
    return custom_cv
```

I'm sure, SURE, that the index that are stored in the zip object is correct with X_train, what I'm saying is that there is NO index in folds that are out of shape of X_train (last index is 4535 and X_train.shape[0] is 4536, so it is correct). However, if I run

```
rfa2_search.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

it gets the error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

If I run with an integer value in cv (for ex cv=5), the call of .fit method will not produce the error so the error is in folds = walk_forward(..) but I'm sure (I print and check manually) that the indexes obtained with walk_forward are compatible.
Moreover, I've already used the folds from walk_forward as a parameter for GridSearchCV and it works!!!
So the problem, imho, is of RFA implemented

What can I do for solving this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the function as follows:

```
def walk_forward(df_train, n_fold, zip_, skl):

total_points = df_train.shape[0] # 5000

sub_val_points = int(0.5 * total_points / n_fold) # 500
sub_train_points = int(total_points - sub_val_points * n_fold) # 2500

custom_cv, arr_tra, arr_val = [], [], []

step = sub_val_points # non overlapping criteria
pos = 0

if skl:  
    for _ in range(n_fold):
        arr_tra.append(np.arange(pos, pos + sub_train_points))
        arr_val.append(np.arange(pos + sub_train_points, pos + sub_train_points + sub_val_points))
        
        pos += step   
    if zip_:
        return zip(arr_tra, arr_val)
    else:
        return [arr_tra, arr_val]    
else:    
    for _ in range(n_fold):
        arr_tra = np.arange(pos, pos + sub_train_points)
        arr_val = np.arange(pos + sub_train_points, pos + sub_train_points + sub_val_points)
        
        pos += step
        arr = (arr_tra, arr_val)
        custom_cv.append(arr)  
    if zip_:
        return zip(custom_cv)
    else:
        return custom_cv
```

The was in the documentation of feature_engine libraries: it accepts as a custom fold the same way of one obtained with Kfold.
I've discovered this after infinitely try, hope someone find this helpful!